# Using Union function in loop in R

Tags: r, loops, union

B and C.

```
A <- 1:5
B <- 3:7
C <- 6:10
```

now I want to take union of these three vectors.
I am doing like this :

```
uni <- union (A,union(B,C))
```

But is there any way to do it in loop or something if have more than three vectors of which I need to take the union of ??

Comment: `unique(c(A,B,C))` gets you the result you need without using any loops at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine these into a `list` and then use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(union, list(A, B, C))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```